Zeros at the end of input message to sha-256
If input message to sha-256 is ended with some non zero amount of 0s, does these 0s count to message length value which is placed at the end of 512-bit block, or length of input message is counted untill last 1 bit in that message?
For example, regardless of it's contents, input message is 447 bits long, so when preparing it for calculating sha-256, there is appended bit with value 1 and then length that has constant value of 447 in 64-bit representation. Then message can be of form 100000...0000 (1 and 446 0s) and it's length will still be 447.
